# Can we use the UIPicker directly in an iPad Application?

Tags: ipad, uipickerview

Can we use the UIPicker directly in an iPad Application? I tried to show a Pickerview. But I felt it very small in size compared to the iPad Dimension. I was also not able to increase its height and width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following lines in the [iPad Human interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadHIG/UIElements/UIElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009446-CH6-SW27)...

> Present a picker or date and time picker only within a popover. This placement differs from the placement recommendation for an iPhone application.

So as Apple suggests it is good to Present the Picker in  a popover rather than in a plain view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it in your iPad application. I wouldn't change it's height and width because the visual elements are setup for a fixed size. But, if you want to you can do it through initWithFrame like so:

```
UIPickerView *pv = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
```

Comment: Hi Charlie,

I checked what you have suggested me (somedays back), but the frame size did not go beyond a certain size. Thanks for your Answer and time. I am closing this question.